# Class not found exception even if the jar is on the classpath / debugging classpath problems

Tags: java, classpath

I'm stumped, I try to run my simple program like this:

```
java -cp ~/FirmwareUpdate/bin:~/PureJavaHidApi/bin/purejavahidapi.jar:~/PureJavaHidApi/lib/jna-4.0.0.jar Test
```

and I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: purejavahidapi/InputReportListener
```

in the point in code where it first accesses that class.

I've read dozens of answers here in SO and elsewhere but have not found the answer.

Comment: Don't use `~`.  *However* ... you might be able to use `$HOME`: `java -cp $HOME/FirmwareUpdate/bin:$HOME/PureJavaHidApi/bin/purejavahidapi.jar:$HOME/PureJavaHidApi/lib/jna-4.0.0.jar Test`

Comment: Thanks, that is correct and I like the tip of using $HOME because specifying the full path is a bore even in adhoc invocations like this.

Comment: Hi @nyholku, Is purejavahidapi wokring ok? I am thinking about using it for my project in the future.

Comment: @NeoPham Yes I think it works for most people most of the time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The penny finally dropped.

The problem is that home directory '~' references do not work except for the first entry in the classpath, which really threw me off the track. Because it worked on for the first entry I thought it would work for the others.

The problem comes from (and is easy to see with hindsight) that the home directory path expansion is done by the shell and to the shell the whole classpath entry looks like a single argument and hence the expansion happens only once at the beginning of the argument.

I confirmed this by writing this simple bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash 
 for i; do 
    echo $i 
 done
```

saved it as 'test' and tried my command line like this:

```
./test -cp ~/FirmwareUpdate/bin:~/PureJavaHidApi/bin/purejavahidapi.jar:~/PureJavaHidApi/lib/jna-4.0.0.jar Test
```

which outputs:

```
-cp
/Users/nyholku/FirmwareUpdate/bin:~/PureJavaHidApi/bin/purejavahidapi.jar:~/PureJavaHidApi/lib/jna-4.0.0.jar
Test
```

confirming the diagnose.

Comment: you can even export your class path as a variable and then refer to that like this   
`export MY_CLASS_PATH= ~/FirmwareUpdate/bin:~/PureJavaHidApi/bin/purejavahidapi.jar:~/PureJavaHidApi/lib/jna-4.0.0.jar <br/>
 java -cp .:$MY_CLASS_PATH Test`

Comment: Right, thanks. I know that and most of the other ways to make this work. This was just a one liner that I used to adhoc test my code from the command line and when it did not work and I could not figure out what was the problem with that particular command line (because I thought I knew my -cp and java stuff) I started to investigate and it really took me long to find out. So I thought it might help other as I was not able to find this particular problem from anywhere.

Comment: yes i understood that when you answered ur own question, i added this in the comments so that others come looking for your link might find it useful :)